# In Crystal Reports, boolean parameter to select both true and false

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Using CR 2008.

I have a Boolean parameter with true and false values which works fine.  Is there a way to add a third option to show both such as 'True, False, Show All'?

Without setting the parameter to allow multiple values.  I.e. By setting the parameter to allow multiple values I can then just select both true and false. Not what I want - I want 3 single options as mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some examples of how you are using and how you would like to use the parameter in a formula might be helpful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a String parameter.
Assume a convention.
Create a formula:

```
if {?MyParameter} = "True" then
  //do stuff like when was true
else if {?MyParameter} = "False" then
  //do stuff like when was false
else
  //do new stuff: not true, not false
```